# Jquery attr isn't working when trying to replace a div img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change a main image for thumbnails when i click, but attr isn't working, i don't know why.

```js
$(document).ready ( function () {
$('#miniatura img').click(function(){

var camin = $(this).attr('src');

    $('#imagem_main').attr('src',camin);
    
});

});
```

```html
<figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
   <div id="main-image-gallery"> <img width="600" height="600" src="bolo1-1000x1000-600x600.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_single size-woocommerce_single" alt="Bolo de Brigadeiro" title="bolo1" data-caption="" data-src="bolo1-1000x1000.jpg" data-large_image="bolo1-1000x1000.jpg" data-large_image_width="1000" data-large_image_height="1000" id="imagem_main" srcset="bolo1-1000x1000-600x600.jpg 600w, sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" /></div>  
     
     
     <div id ="miniatura">
     
     <img width="100" height="100" src="bolo2.jpg" class="attachment-100x100 size-100x100" alt="" title="bolo2" data-caption="" data-src="bolo2.jpg" data-large_image="bolo2.jpg" data-large_image_width="1000" data-large_image_height="1000" id="" srcset="bolo2-100x100.jpg 100w" sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" />
     
     <img width="100" height="100" src="bolo3.jpg" class="attachment-100x100 size-100x100" alt="" title="bolo3" data-caption="" data-src="bolo3.jpg" data-large_image="bolo3.jpg" data-large_image_width="1000" data-large_image_height="1000" id="" srcset="bolo3 100w," sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" /> </div></figure>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Are you including jQuery on the page?

Comment: How did you add the JS code? Try to replace all instances of `$` with `jQuery` and check again.

Comment: include jquery in your html file: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>`